# How to prevent null and duplicate records in table using mysql?

Tags: mysql

i am using mysql as back end in my android app but i want to do some if any user try to enter null record (empty fields) than it can't write in mysql table is it possible to prevent to entering null record in table.

Comment: actually i want to prevent user to insert empty(null) records in table.

Comment: You need to prevent it from front end instead of back end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mark the columns as `NOT NULL`. This will prevent any NULL value to be entered in those columns.The query will fail to execute if a `NULL` value is entered. In the front end you can display an error msg if the if the query fails, to let the user enter the correct value.

Comment: i hve made table from phpmyadmin and at that time i hve set that column as NOT NULL, but still when i enter null record it can insert in table.

Comment: can you paste your sql query in your question.?

Answer (score 0):

Do validation when you are entering value into mysql, Or you can store default value for that column if front end side field is not compulsory.

Always do a validation do not push data into database blindly.